# Configuring a webservice at deployment time

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

With Session Beans I can use the ejb-jar.xml file to create multiple 'configurations' from the same java class at deployment time which are set to use different data sources or have other 'deployment time' configurations.

Consider the Stateless Session Bean class

```
    package myexample;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    @Stateless
    @Remote(MyRemote.class)
    public class MyBean  implements MyRemote {

        private javax.sql.DataSource theDS;

        @Resource(name = "beanName")
    private String beanName;

    public int add(String tag, int val) throws AppException
    {
        try {
            Connection c = null;
            Statement s = null;
            ResultSet r = null;
            int lastValue;
            try {
                c = theDB.getConnection();

    ...snip...
    }
}
```

And the ejb-jar.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <display-name>EJB1</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>Bean1</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>myexample.MyBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>beanName</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>Bean1</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>java:/MSSQLDSXA</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
                <injection-target>
                    <injection-target-class>myexample.MyBean</injection-target-class>
                    <injection-target-name>theDS</injection-target-name>
                </injection-target>
            </resource-ref>

        </session>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>Bean2</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>myexample.MyBean</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>beanName</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>Bean2</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
            <resource-ref>
                <res-ref-name>java:/MSSQLDSXA2</res-ref-name>
                <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
                <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
                <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
                <injection-target>
                    <injection-target-class>myexample.MyBean</injection-target-class>
                    <injection-target-name>theDS</injection-target-name>
                </injection-target>
            </resource-ref>

        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I can lookup 2 different bean 'configurations' which will bind to different database instances and have different values for beanName; (*this is a Jboss AS7.1, using the ejb context*).

```
            UserTransaction utx = null;
        InitialContext ctx = getInitialContext();

        utx = EJBClient.getUserTransaction("hath");
        utx.setTransactionTimeout(900);
        utx.begin();

        try {
                MyRemote bean = (MyRemote) ctx
        .lookup("ejb:MyEJBModule/Bean1!myexample.MyRemote");
                MyRemote bean2 = (MyRemote) ctx
        .lookup("ejb:MyEJBModule/Bean2!myexample.MyRemote");
                bean1.add("ThisRow", 1);
                bean2.add("ThisRow", 2);

...
```

Supposing I want to use this SSB as the implementation for a WebService, how can I then create 2 instances of the WebService which mimic the way that the 2 SSBs bind to different configurations?

Is there a webservice equivalent of ejb-jar.xml which is app server independent? Obviously I would need to override the location of the webservice etc.. The old JAX-RPC mechanism had a webservices.xml file and a mapping file. Are either of these still pertinent, and how would I link to the ejb-jar.xml file?

If there is no generic java EE way of doing this, is one available in JBoss 7.1+?

Or will I have to generate multiple classes just for doing deployment time configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JBoss AS7.1 you can use the JBoss specific deployment file `jboss-webservices.xml`

This is briefly described in the  [JBossWS Adavanced User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Advanced+User+Guide#AdvancedUserGuide-Configurationthroughdeploymentdescriptor)

First add the @WebService annotation to the bean class

```
@Stateless
@Remote(MyRemote.class)
@WebService
public class MyBean  implements MyRemote {
```

To create 2 web services based on the 2 session beans above create a jboss-webservices.xml with the following content and place it with the ejb-jar.xml in the META-INF directory.

```
<webservices xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      version="1.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_webservices_1_0.xsd">
      <port-component>
        <ejb-name>Bean1</ejb-name> 
        <port-component-name>Bean1</port-component-name>
        <port-component-uri>/Bean1</port-component-uri>
      </port-component>
      <port-component>
        <ejb-name>Bean2</ejb-name>
        <port-component-name>Bean2</port-component-name>
        <port-component-uri>/Bean2</port-component-uri>
      </port-component>
</webservices>
```

Yes, that's all that is needed.
Having generated a client proxy using the URL of one of the webservices, you can then specify their WSDL URLs at runtime to get the client to talk to either one of them;

```
Bean1 service  = new Bean1Service(new URL("http://localhost:8080/MyEJBModule/Bean1?wsdl"), new QName("http://myexample/", "Bean1Service")).getBean1Port();
Bean1 service3 = new Bean1Service(new URL("http://localhost:8080/MyEJBModule/Bean2?wsdl"), new QName("http://myexample/", "Bean1Service")).getBean1Port();

System.out.println(service.add("TEST", 100));
System.out.println("Bean3: " + service3.add("TEST", 100));
```

The 2 add calls effect different database instances...